Issue with Extracting API Data Using Airbyte Builder
I am using Airbyte (version 0.63.11) to hit an API and retrieve details for a specific trading pair. I'm utilizing the builder feature of Airbyte to construct and send the API request. Below is the request I am firing:
{
  "url": "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?startTime=1721964898&interval=1m&symbol=ETHBTC",
  "headers": {
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.32.3",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Connection": "keep-alive"
  },
  "http_method": "GET",
  "body": ""
}

I receive the following response (shortened version for brevity):
{
  "status": 200,
  "body": [
    [
      1500004800000,
      "0.08000000",
      "0.08000000",
      "0.08000000",
      "0.08000000",
      "0.04300000",
      1500004859999,
      "0.00344000",
      1,
      "0.00000000",
      "0.00000000",
      "0"
    ],
    [
      1500004860000,
      "0.08000000",
      "0.08000000",
      "0.08000000",
      "0.08000000",
      "0.00000000",
      1500004919999,
      "0.00000000",
      0,
      "0.00000000",
      "0.00000000",
      "0"
    ],
    [
      1500004920000,
      "0.08000000",
      "0.08000000",
      "0.08000000",
      "0.08000000",
      "0.30600000",
      1500004979999,
      "0.02448000",
      2,
      "0.00000000",
      "0.00000000",
      "0"
    ]
  ]
}

However, I am unable to extract the response data. I believe the issue is due to the untyped array of arrays called body in the response. Below is the exception I am encountering:
ERROR

Something went wrong in the connector. See the logs for more details. - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airbyte/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airbyte_cdk/sources/abstract_source.py", line 133, in read
    yield from self._read_stream(
  File "/home/airbyte/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airbyte_cdk/sources/abstract_source.py", line 232, in _read_stream
    for record_data_or_message in record_iterator:
  File "/home/airbyte/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airbyte_cdk/sources/streams/core.py", line 190, in read
    for record_data_or_message in records:
  File "/home/airbyte/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airbyte_cdk/sources/declarative/declarative_stream.py", line 136, in read_records
    yield from self.retriever.read_records(self.get_json_schema(), stream_slice)
  File "/home/airbyte/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airbyte_cdk/sources/declarative/retrievers/simple_retriever.py", line 375, in read_records
    for stream_data in self._read_pages(record_generator, self.state, _slice):
  File "/home/airbyte/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airbyte_cdk/sources/declarative/retrievers/simple_retriever.py", line 299, in _read_pages
    yield from records_generator_fn(response)
  File "/home/airbyte/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airbyte_cdk/sources/declarative/retrievers/simple_retriever.py", line 445, in _parse_records
    yield from self._parse_response(
  File "/home/airbyte/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airbyte_cdk/sources/declarative/retrievers/simple_retriever.py", line 245, in _parse_response
    for record in record_generator:
  File "/home/airbyte/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airbyte_cdk/sources/declarative/extractors/record_selector.py", line 67, in select_records
    for data in normalized_data:
  File "/home/airbyte/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airbyte_cdk/sources/declarative/extractors/record_selector.py", line 76, in _normalize_by_schema
    normalized_record = dict(record)
TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence

ERROR

None - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airbyte/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airbyte_cdk/connector_builder/message_grouper.py", line 302, in _read_stream
    yield from AirbyteEntrypoint(source).read(source.spec(self.logger), config, configured_catalog, state)
  File "/home/airbyte/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airbyte_cdk/entrypoint.py", line 166, in read
    for message in self.source.read(self.logger, config, catalog, state):
  File "/home/airbyte/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airbyte_cdk/sources/declarative/manifest_declarative_source.py", line 167, in read
    yield from super().read(logger, config, catalog, state)
  File "/home/airbyte/.pyenv/versions/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airbyte_cdk/sources/abstract_source.py", line 186, in read
    raise AirbyteTracedException(message=error_message, failure_type=FailureType.config_error)
airbyte_cdk.utils.traced_exception.AirbyteTracedException: None

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide guidance on how to properly extract the response data in these scenarios using Airbyte Builder? I believe the issue is because of the untyped array of arrays in the response key : body, Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.
